# Get result based on latest status set in joined table

Tags: mysql, datetime, join

Good morning!

I have the following database setup:

- table orders: contains all orders, including the respective shop
- table shops_status: contains all status per shop
- table orders_status: contains the order_id, the status_id of that respective shop and status, and the date the status has been set

here are the db statements (without indizes and so on, there are many more columns, but I'll only note the necessary ones, the queries won't be executeable):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS d02bc910.orders (
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  shops_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS d02bc910.shops_status (
  shops_status_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  shops_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  translations_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   <= the software's multilingual so I use translations here
  status_order TINYINT(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (shops_status_id);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS d02bc910.orders_status (
  order_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  status_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  users_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  updatedAt DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

What I want to do now is to create a report containing all orders matching various search parameters, including the latest status for that respective order. But I don't know how to combine the JOIN to orders_status with the last set status_id.
I could do it in a PHP foreach afterwards but then I'd either have to collect all ids first, run a statement and then match the results but I guess there is a way to do this within SQL.

Can anybody help me with this, please?

Thanks in advance, S

Comment: I am confused by this schema. I an see there is a relationship between orders and orders_status (orders.id = orders_status.order_id) but I don't understand where shops_status comes into it or where the most recent status comes from. You could clarify the question by adding sample data and expected output as text.

Comment: the table shops_status holds all status an order for this shop can have, so I wanted to join the table shops_status using shops_status_id  ...  the name of the keys don't match and I'm actually not really satisfied with it myself but I'll fix that later

Comment: in the result I'd like to have the order and the last status set for that order